# bxSlider adaptive height doesn't work on first load page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bxslider

i'm using bxSlider 4.1.2, each slide has different height (contains paragraphs and images), so i add the option `adaptiveHeight:true` based on [bxSlider AdaptiveHeight](http://bxslider.com/examples/slideshow-adaptive-height). when first load page, the slider's height following the tallest slider, so it looks like a long gap between first slide and the controller buttons. like this : [image: the problem]

i want my slider in first load is looks like this :
[image: what i want]

i'm calling the bxSlider in `$(document).ready();` event , i was trying using event `$(window).load();` but it brokes my slider :(

this is my javascript now

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
slider_custom1 = $('#slider_brand1').bxSlider({
controls: true,
autoControls: true,
adaptiveHeight: true,
pagerCustom: '#custom_bullets1',
nextSelector: '#slider-next1',
prevSelector: '#slider-prev1',
nextText: '<img src="<?php echo base_url('webroot/images/next_detail_product.png');?>" />',
prevText: '<img src="<?php echo base_url('webroot/images/prev_detail_product.png');?>" />'
});
});
```

Comment: just give us fiddle demo...@vanio

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vdp1708/qLSGe/81/ it's work in fiddle, but not on my page scripts :( what supposed i do

Comment: have you checked your console..? try to solve console errors..@vanio

Comment: i also have same issue